# How to compare two dataframe based on column name of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes like this:

df1:

```
Product  pricing_type
prod1    I
prod2    p
prod3    E
```

df2:

```
id  internal_price  external price pilot_price
1    0.7             0.89             0.3
```

The output I want:
df3

```
Product  pricing_type  price
prod1    I              0.7
prod2    P              0.3
prod3    E              0.89
```

How can I achieve this efficiently?

Comment: Is multiple rows in `df2` ? Do you need match values by `pricing_type` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use for better performance first `rename` columns and then [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
d = {'internal_price':'I','external price':'E','pilot_price':'p'}
df2 = df2.rename(columns=d).melt('id', var_name='pricing_type', value_name='price')
print (df2)
   id pricing_type  price
0   1            I   0.70
1   1            E   0.89
2   1            p   0.30
```

And last add to `df1` like:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='pricing_type', how='left')
```

Comment: why melt and not transpose? what's the difference?

Comment: @Qdr - because I think in `df2` is multiple rows.

Comment: Even thought ```df2``` is multiple rows, Transpose would just turn those rows into columns. Then from there you can loop through the columns to get the one you want

Comment: @swagless_monk - Why use loops if need always avoid it if need performance?

Comment: If I understand that correctly, a single loop will not drastically impact performance.

Comment: @swagless_monk - hmmm, it depends. If need apply your solution in loop for each row, then it is much slowier like using `melt` here.

Comment: @swagless_monk - If you think I am wrong, please add some timings e.g. for 1k, 10k rows for prove I am wrong.

Comment: Coding is unique in that there are many ways to handle the same problem. Pandas has a natural limit to the amount of rows it can handle so I assume for any large number of rows ```pyspark``` would be used. But if this is just pandas I would transpose.

Comment: @swagless_monk - agree. I only explain loops are not good idea in pandas generally, so I always prefer non loops solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of the transpose method. For this problem, it seems like you don't really need to worry about joining on a particular field, but just to move one column from `df2` to `df1`

```
#transpose the dataframe with the row values
df2 = df2.T.reset_index()

#column you want to join (since the 'id' value from df2 is 1)
prices = df2[1]

#add column to dataframe
df1 = df1.join(prices)
```

If you wanted to move multiple rows, you would just change

```
#column you want to join
prices = df2[1]

#add column to dataframe
df1 = df1.join(prices)
```

to

```
for col in df2:
    df1 = df1.join(df2[col])
```

and select the columns you need